# When scale up pod in k8s ingress session affinity error

Tags: docker, kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

I am running a python application which is having react bundle.

Currently, i am running single pod of application everything seems to work fine but when i was scaling up to pod number 2-3 it's creating an issue in some case not able to login into the application.

in ingress, i have added 
 ingress yaml config is :

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: admin-ingress
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"
    certmanager.k8s.io/cluster-issuer: admin-prod
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "true"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/secure-backends: "true"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/affinity: "cookie"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/session-cookie-name : "session"
spec:
  tls:
  - hosts:
    - domain
    secretName: admin-prod
  rules:
  - host: domain
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        backend:
          serviceName: admin-service
          servicePort: 80
```

Comment: this is very unusual issue for Kubernetes. Can you describe your application a little bit more, how it works?

Comment: It is having simple python application when python script start it build front end package and rediness probe start the probe to take request.

Comment: I solved the issue using `nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/affinity: "cookie"` can you please help me to understand this issue.

Comment: Without complete view of your environment and YAML manifests it is impossible to help you, sorry. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @VasilyAngapov I have updated question please check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears like you are storing user session info in cookie.

nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/affinity: "cookie"

the above setting would enable sticky session using the cookie. say, user is connected to replica-1. his session info is stored in cookie. he gets logged out and logs in back, he would be taken to replica-1.

Comment: When i scale up pod to number of replica 3 then i am not able to login from some browser.

Comment: I have updated whole question with yaml file. please check